# Sync multiple component's form data on submit

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, angular-components

I have **8 components** from step1 to step8 in accordion and **save** button is in HomeComponent, so it will look like:

```
 <app-step1></app-step1>
 <app-step2></app-step2>
 <app-step3></app-step3>
 <app-step4></app-step4>
 <app-step5></app-step5>
 <app-step6></app-step6>
 <app-step7></app-step7>
 <app-step8></app-step8>
```

I too have to save form data on **next** button in every step component. I'm using reactive forms.

**My Strategy:**

I'm using service (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) to handle communication between components.

Every component will send form data to HomeComponent when save button clicked.

Basically I'm counting how many steps sending their form data to HomeComponent and if count is equal to total form count then I am saving data.

```
this.formCount++;

if(this.totalFormCount == this.formCount)
{
      if(this.formShouldBeSaved)
      {
        this.formCount = 0;

        return this.save();
      }
      else
      {
        this.openAccordion(this.invalidFormName);
      }
      this.formCount = 0;
}
```

So is there any better way to handle above situation ?